# How to change view after user tap push notification - Firebase - Native Script

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, push-notification, nativescript

I'm trying to make sure that when the user clicks on the push notification balloon, the app opens and goes to a specific page.

I'm using Nativescript with firebase. Here is the code segment of `app.component.tns.ts` :

```js
firebase.init({
  showNotificationsWhenInForeground: true,
  onMessageReceivedCallback: (message) => {
    if (message.foreground) {
      alert('app is open');
    } else {
      console.log('app background');
      this.routerExtensions.navigate(["messages"] ); 
    }
  }
})
```

When app is foreground the alert is shown, when the app is background and I tap the notification, the console log is printed but then nothing happens.

**UPDATE**

When I say app in background this mean app is still alive, and when clicking on notification the app start from splash screen.

Comment: When you say app in background, app is still alive or killed? Clicking on notification makes the app to start from splash screen?

Answer (score 0):

- Your routing path seems relative `["messages"]`, I think it should be absolute `["/messages"]`.
- With Angular you will have to run the navigation inside zone, the firebase callback is executed outside zone.

  ```
     this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/messages']))
  ```

Comment: does not work, didn't enter into zone.run() , this is entered into app.component, rigth?

Answer (score -1):

You should use the firebase.addOnMessageReceivedCallback() function for this. This something that is mentioned on the official github for nativescript firebase project.

[https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/MESSAGING.md](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpxw9.png)

```html
firebase.addOnMessageReceivedCallback((message) => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['messages']);
      });
  });
```

Comment: does not work, didn't enter into zone.run